# Почему парсер ничего не выводит? python

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
global URL
URL = 'https://lolz.guru/threads/3267112/'

def parse():
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0',
        "Accept-Encoding": "*",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = "messageInfo", id="post-27900440")
    sms = []
    for user in items:
        sms.append({
            'name': item.find('a', class_='username').get_text(strip=True),
            'txt': item.find('blockquote', class_='messageText SelectQuoteContainer baseHtml ugc  ').get_text(strip=True),
            'link': item.find('a', class_='item messageDateHeader datePermalink hashPermalink OverlayTrigger muted')['href']
        })
    return sms

print(parse())
```

В итоге код выводит пустой список.

Только начал в этом разбираться, с других сайтов всё нормально парсил

Comment: В __response.content__ возвращается вот это: "Oops! Please enable JavaScript and Cookies in your browser.". Поэтому bs ничего не находит.

Comment: Придётся вам изучать ещё и `Selenium`, видимо